# Quelle traduction imagée pour « a baker's dozen » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques, nombres

*A baker's dozen* (la douzaine du boulanger) signifie 13. L'expression daterait d'une époque où les boulangers donnaient treize pains au lieu de douze pour éviter de se faire traiter de voleurs si l'un d'eux était creux, par exemple. Il faut dire qu'on coupait la main d'un voleur, en ces temps-là.

Existe-t-il une expression similaire en français ? J'entends par là une expression qui signifie *treize*. Il existe bien *treize à la douzaine*, mais je cherchais quelque chose de plus imagé, qui requiert une certaine connaissance générale pour en déduire que ça vaut 13.

Answer (score 4):

"Une douzaine bien tassée" ?

Un peu comme on dirait "la quarantaine bien tassée" pour quelqu'un avoisinant, voire dépassant les cinquante ans. Mais je reconnais qu'on ne peut pas garantir que l'auteur voulait vraiment dire 13, ni 14, ni 12...

Answer (score 1):

Le *[treizain](http://collectionneurs-bergeracois.fr/?p=255)* reprend le principe de treize pour 'garantir' douze.

Et si l'on n'est pas bloqué sur une numération duodécimale et que l'on veut indiquer un 'plus' donné gratuitement dans le même esprit de remplacer d'éventuels défaut unitaire : 
En rajouter un pour faire bon poids.

Comment: Voir aussi le treizain à https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treizain et même... la treizaine : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treizaine ; mais je ne suis pas sûr que tout cela ait un rapport avec la question ?... en tous les cas, ça existe.

Comment: Effectivement, comme le dit @Istao, tu as donné une bonne réponse, mais pas à la bonne question. +1 tout de même, parce que je me coucherai moins ignorant.